# A bat vs bats vs the bats

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Which one of these sentences is correct:

> A bat is not a bird, but a mammal.

or

> Bats are not birds but mammals

or

> The bats are not birds but mammals.

Answer (score 3):

Both of the examples:

> - A bat is not a bird, but a mammal.
> - Bats are not birds but mammals

are correct. The choice of whether to use singular or plural forms is purely one of style. The meaning is identical.  The third example:

> - The bats are not birds but mammals.

is not incorrect. It uses "the bats" to refer to bats as a (specified) group. It is a bit more formal, and the extra words do not, in this case, add anything to the meaning.  Some writers use a definite article with a singular form in such a construction, such as:

> - The bat is not a bird, but a mammal.

This is not grammatically incorrect, but in my view is always a mistake. It implies that bats are a singular kind of thing, whereas in fact there are a number of different species of bats. This form disregards those differences, and indeed implies that they are unimportant.  The late biologist and essayist Stephan Jay Gould wrote that the use of such forms as "The bat", "the whale", or "The monkey" when referring to entire wide groups was generally a mark of careless and lazy writing about nature. I agree, and advise avoiding such forms.

Comment: The bats [in the attic] are not birds but mammals. That's fine. And in formal writing: "The bat is not a mammal." is fine, where "The bat" is used for "bats". The cow was domesticated at a late date.=Cows were domesticated at a late date.

Comment: The construction where "The Bat" is used for all bats, or "the cow" is used for all cows, is precisely the construction which I argue is typically used by lazy writers, and should be avoided, particularly in formal but popular accounts. It is grammatical, but obscures key facts to no gain.

Comment: This construction  falsely implies that "The bat" is a thing, while in fact it is a collection of multiple species with significant differences. Diversity is a key characteristic of nature, and an essentialist viewpoint obscures this reality.

Comment: @DavidSiegel  +1  I think you are clear that "the bat" is grammatical, but you personally don't approve of it.  I consider it a kind of *affectation*, but not something I'd condemn or even pay much attention to..

Comment: @Andrew It is not only my personal view. The late S. J. Gould expressed it several times, and he was a very noted writer on this specific topic.

Comment: Constructions where "the bat" is used for all bats is most definitely in the grammar books and in formal writing. Especially stuff like zoology. "The bat emits high-pitched sounds (up to 100,000 hertz) that echo from objects it encounters; " https://www.factmonster.com/encyclopedia/ecology/animals/vertebrates/bat/special-characteristics

Comment: Here is a good example even though from Wikipedia: the giraffe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giraffe

Comment: @Lambie Thank you. as an experie4nced Wikipedia editor, i will correct that at once.

Comment: Sorry to be so insistent. I learned this many moons ago when I had to teach legal English to French uni students. I am sure Mr. Gould would have agreed with: The harpy fruit bat obviously lives on fruit. I don't think it was the the that bothered him; it was the not identifying the species that probably did...:)

Comment: @Lambie and particularly the use of "the" to describe a group including multipel species, even multiple higher groups such as 'the fish". But even "The harpy fruit bat": while not making this error seems to implicitly assume an essentialist attitude I have now edited the Wikipedia article on Giraffe to use plural forms. Yes this construction is often used. I maintain that it is typically an indication of poor writing, often of copying/imitating  tertiary or quarternary  texts.

Comment: @Lambie " The cow was domesticated at a late date"  which cow? The Asian ox? The sub-Saharan african oix? The dessart kine? The North American Longhorn?  The Buffalo? Those are all "cows" but they were not all domesticated at the same time -- some never were? The sentence cannot mean what it seems to say, and is therefore poor writing.

Comment: You could take it up with the British Council:https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/definite-article